# sqlite database continues to insert the default admin

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create a system with a predefined admin and then the new admin can update the information after entering the database.

In the first time I use the system, it does add the default admin but once I update the admin and re-open the system. it adds the default admin again.

Here is the code for the default admin insert.

```
with sqlite3.connect('esr.db') as db:
   c = db.cursor()
   c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admin (adminuser TEXT NOT NULL ,password TEXT NOT NULL);')
   c.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM admin')
   count = c.fetchall()
   if len(count) == 0:
       insert = 'INSERT INTO admin(adminuser,password) VALUES(?,?)'
       c.execute(insert,['admin', 'password'])
   db.commit()
   db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious to me why it is inserting the default again.  Here are two solutions for avoiding this.

The first is to do the check in the insert:

```
insert into admin (adminuser, password)
    select adminuser, password
    from (select ? as adminuser, ? as password) x
    where not exists (select 1 from admin);
```

The second is to do the check when you define the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admin (
    adminuser TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    password TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

This will prevent duplicates from being inserted.

In either case, you should not be storing passwords as free text.  It should always be encrypted.

Comment: @anooAr . . . Such a comment provides no help at all.  Which doesn't work?  Do you get an error?  What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
This is how I solved it.

> find_user = ('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE adminuser = ?')
>   c.execute(find_user,['admin'])
>   result01 = c.fetchall()
>   if len(result01)==0:
>      insert = 'INSERT INTO admin(adminuser,password) VALUES(?,?)'
>      c.execute(insert,['admin', 'pass'])